# angularjs dynamic model in directive from json object

Tags: angularjs, json, directive, angular-ngmodel

I have a json file of objects that store the properties to be used in a directive.
I want to use the json obj model value in the directive, but nothing I am trying is working.

Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong / missing? I find this very confusing.
Hope someone can help been trying this for days now!

---

**Edit::** 
I have a $http service that gets and returns the Json object and I can access the properties fine.

I am specifically trying to use the value of the json obj model property -- "model" : "ticketData.contactname" as the dynamic value of the ng-model.

If I just use the ticketData.contactname obj then it works fine and I can edit the model value, but if I try and use the string from the Json obj then it just prints the string into the input box.

I do not know what to do. I am sure it is something basic I am missing.

---

Thanks in advance

Json sample:

```
[
    {
        "inputsContact" : [
            { 
                "labelName" : "Contact Name",
                "placeholder" : "Enter your name",
                "model" : "ticketData.contactname",
                "type" : "text"
            }
    }
]
```

Html sample:

```
<text-input-comp inputdata="contactName" ng-model="contactModel">    </text-input-comp>
```

Directive text-input-comp:

```
.directive('textInputComp', [ '$compile', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      inputData: '=inputdata',
      modelData: '=ngModel'
    },
    templateUrl: '/app/views/partials/components/textInputComp.html'
  }
}]);
```

Directive template sample:

```
<label> {{ inputData.labelName }} </label> 
<input type="text" ng-model="modelData" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" placeholder="{{ inputData.placeholder }}"  /> 
<div ></div>
```

Controller sample:

```
$scope.contactName = $scope.inputData[0].inputsContact[0];
$scope.contactModel = $scope.inputData[0].inputsContact[0].model;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to get  the json file first then do all the manupilation

have a look at this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
    {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("customers.json").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data.records;
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What u were missing is this 
Just replace the customer.json file with your json and u are good to go 
and

1.$http is service responsible for communicating with other file. $http says get file from ‘js/data.json’ and if the operation is a ‘success’ then execute a function holding the ‘data’ which it got automatically from data.json file
to make u understand.

2.A one more line above: [‘$scope’, ‘$http’, function($scope, $http){ … }] is little bit tricky: it takes an array holding two objects one is $scope and other is a service i.e $http. The reason we have this in array is angularJS automatically minifies code which means it removes extra spaces and shorten variable names for faster performance but sometimes this minification causes trouble so we just told controller NOT to minify $scope, $http services and function inside array.

Comment: Hi @Prateek,
Thanks for looking into this.

I already have a service for this - just didn't think it was useful to add to question.
this is what I have:

        //In Controller :::  prepare data to create inputs
 $scope.inputData = [];
 BuildInputService.getInputs(function(response) {
  $scope.inputData = response.data;
 });


        //In Services
        .factory('BuildInputService', ['$http',  function($http) {
 return {
  getInputs: function( callback ) {
   $http.get('app/data/input-creation-data.json')
   .then(function(response) {
    callback( response );
   });
  }
 };
      }])